# how to create widget in android

Tags: android

how to create widgets in android i dnt know nothing please any boby help me to create this widget and tell me each and every s

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On Android developer site you will find good tutorials:

1. [widget_design](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html)
2. [appwidgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)
3. [android_howto-hellowidget](http://www.helloandroid.com/files/xmaswidget/android_howto-hellowidget.pdf)

For more search on google you will find lots of out there.

Answer (score 5):

There are bunch of resources on Widget development at android SDK, some of it:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html
- http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/introducing-home-screen-widgets-and.html